# Has gcloud run changed minimum memory limits?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

A recent cloud run project previously deployed fine with memory limit of 128MB (`--memory 128M`) but this failed today with the error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Invalid value specified for memory. For 1.0
> CPU, memory must be between 128Mi and 4Gi inclusive.

Changing the config to `--memory 128Mi` resolved the issue but since a mebibyte is larger than a megabyte this looks like a change to me though [there's not much indication of minimum limits on the docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/memory-limits) or [quota pages](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas). Anyway, for info and in case anyone else can confirm...

Answer (score 4):

Might have been an update to Kubernetes... I use to be able to use `gcloud run deploy` without specifying cpu, memory, etc.

Now if I don't specify these settings I get:

> ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) spec.template.spec.containers[0].resources.limits.cpu: Invalid value specified for cpu. For the specified value, maxScale may not exceed 10.

Had to set `--max-instances=10` for it to work.

Comment: Same thing when deploying a Cloud Functions gen2, my guess is that the default is max instances of 100 but not all regions support this high number.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but I ran into this issue after changing the region by mistake.
Because apparently:

> The actual maximum limit depends on the region of the Cloud Run service and its CPU and memory configurations.

(Source: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/max-instances#limits)

Answer (score 0):

After the Documentation Updated for Minimum memory configuration in August 2022, you can see the changes as mentioned in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/memory-limits#memory-minimum) :

> The minimum memory setting varies depending on whether you use [first
> generation or second generation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-execution-environments) execution environment:
>
> - 128 MiB for first generation
> - 512 MiB for second generation

You can also refer to the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62074820/15774176) states as:

> The format for size is a fixed or floating point number followed by a
> unit: G, M, or K corresponding to gigabyte, megabyte, or kilobyte,
> respectively, or use the power-of-two equivalents: Gi, Mi, Ki
> corresponding to gibibyte, mebibyte or kibibyte respectively.

Comment: @barclakj Posted an answer, is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

#### TLDR;

Double check that you GCP Cloud Build manifest does not enforce some resources configuration.

#### Break Down

First, I spent months without looking at those deployments. In the mean time, GCP changed some rules around resources. CPU for one was correlated to max number of instances.

I did redeploy on Cloud Run manually with limited max instances but with Cloud Build, it failed with:

```
Deployment failed
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) spec.template.spec.containers.resources.limits.cpu: Invalid value specified for cpu. For the specified value, maxScale may not exceed 5.
Consider running your workload in a region with greater capacity, decreasing your requested cpu-per-instance, or requesting an increase in quota for this region if you are seeing sustained usage near this limit, see https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas. Your project may gain access to further scaling by adding billing information to your account.
```

I happened to have `--max-instances=29` in my Cloud Build step for Cloud Run deployment. Removing it saved <del>the day</del> **the week**.

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone comes here looking. Putting this in your `index.js` file in the functions folder might solve your problem.

```
const {setGlobalOptions} = require("firebase-functions/v2");
setGlobalOptions({maxInstances: 10});
```

At least it solved mine. Original answer at [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76434349/firebase-cloud-functions-v2-error-when-deploying).

You might also need to update your cloud build setting to enable most of the service accounts related to Firebase